# How to disable the automatic opening of CodeSnap screenshots in a split window

Tags: visual-studio-code

whenever I take screenshot with codesnap in vs code it opens it in a spit window, how can a disable it without disabling the entire split in vs code.

It opens like so
[image]

but I want it to open like so
[image]

I want it to open but without spitting vs code editor. It should just open a new tab without spitting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard-coded to open to the side (`vscode.ViewColumn.Beside`). See https://github.com/kufii/CodeSnap/blob/6de4a985c48de8ab69c4258e9406e408f7e5a8d6/src/extension.js#L48. If you want the option to not open it to the side, you'll have to [ask the maintainer of the extension](https://github.com/kufii/CodeSnap/issues/new) to add a setting for where it opens.