# how to open a webview to the side in vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to open a webview to the side (a new tab in a new group) of the current editor like this [markdown extension](https://github.com/shd101wyy/vscode-markdown-preview-enhanced) does, however it opens in the same group of tabs.

Basically I need that the user see the current editor and the webview at same time.

I've tried many combinations of `viewColumn` and `preserveFocus` but didn't work:

```
 vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
  'foo',
  `foooooo`,
 {
   viewColumn: ViewColumn.two,
   preserveFocus: true
 },
  {
    enableScripts: true,
  },
);
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77857344/11107541, https://github.com/shd101wyy/vscode-markdown-preview-enhanced/blob/master/src/extension-common.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A flexible solution requires a combination of editor group creation and the view column option. In my app I have a webview provider that contains this:

```js
    protected createPanel(placement?: string): Promise<boolean> {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            void this.prepareEditorGroup(placement).then((viewColumn) => {
                this.panel = window.createWebviewPanel(
                    "my-webview",
                    this.#caption,
                    { viewColumn, preserveFocus: true },
                    {
                        enableScripts: true,
                        retainContextWhenHidden: true,
                    });

                this.panel.onDidDispose(() => { this.handleDispose(); });
                this.panel.iconPath = {
                    dark: Uri.file(path.join(__dirname, "..", "images", "dark", "mysql.svg")),
                    light: Uri.file(path.join(__dirname, "..", "images", "light", "mysql.svg")),
                };

                this.panel.webview.onDidReceiveMessage((message: IEmbeddedMessage) => {
                    if (message.source === "app") {
                        this.requisitions?.handleRemoteMessage(message);
                    }
                });

                if (this.onStateChange) {
                    this.panel.onDidChangeViewState((event) => {
                        this.onStateChange?.(this, event.webviewPanel.active);
                    });
                }

                // A method which generates the standard content of my webviews.
                prepareWebviewContent(this.panel, this.url);
            });

        });
    }

    private prepareEditorGroup = async (placement?: string): Promise<ViewColumn> => {
        let viewColumn = (!placement || placement === "Active") ? ViewColumn.Active : ViewColumn.Beside;
        if (placement === "Beside Bottom") {
            viewColumn = ViewColumn.Active;
            await commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.editorLayoutTwoRows");
            await commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.focusSecondEditorGroup");
        }

        return viewColumn;
    };
```

The parameter `placement` is a string I store as an extension setting. It can be one of these values: `Active`, `Beside Right`, `Beside Bottom`.

To open a new editor (group) to the bottom, you have to adjust the editor layout first, which is what the two command executions do. Otherwise use `ViewColumn.Beside` for opening a new editor to the right.

Comment: it worked. The only difference is that I needed columns so I've changed the command to `workbench.action.editorLayoutTwoColumns`

Comment: But a second column is automatically created with `ViewColumn.Beside`. The layout change is solely to add a new group below the current one (which doesn't happen automatically). But anyway, glad it works for you.